# Send file to user using bot framework composer

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm really new in BotFramework Composer,I want make a Menu with two options and when I click Option1,the Bot send a File to user, can you please help me?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use adaptive card

Example here

- ```
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.2",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Download File",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "isSubtle": false
    }
  ],
     "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "title": "Click to Download",
            "url": "https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/0/0/D0001082-EEDC-41E2-A7C2-4BD05A7FB63A/BusinessApps_ReleaseNotes_v18.1.4.pdf"
        }
    ]
  ```

}```

Sample UI

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that works for me, can I use AdaptiveCard as a Menu with different Options? because a Menu with two Options

Comment: can you add a sample image how you want ?

Comment: If the answer is fine for you, mark it as answered

Comment: I marked it, thanks. I mean like that [Image](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-03dBNNglgKc/W1PN72dfNgI/AAAAAAAAGQI/iGzzdGrhneEse054zCbVo-FzjPogNEh1QCLcBGAs/s400/Capture1.PNG)

Comment: The "actions" section is an array, Inside the "actions" section you add all the items.